# Обновление WebView с помощью Swipe Refresh

Tags: java, android

Есть элемент *WebView*, который по умолчанию открывает некий сайт.

Хочу сделать возможность обновления просматриваемой страницы, потянув её вниз.

Думаю реализовать это с помощью *Swipe Refresh*. Только вот еще никак не пойму, как это реализовать, поэтому обращаюсь сюда за помощью.

Вот код самого WebView:

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

  android:id="@+id/MasteramWEB"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@menu/main" >

</WebView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот туториал:

[Клик](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/implementing-swipe-to-refresh/)

Вам просто `WebView` нужно поместить в `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

Comment: по возможности, давайте, пожалуйста, чуть более развёрнутые ответы. в частности, с примером кода.